How to access tags for current route from Middleware
Using FastAPI, I have a route like this:
@app.get("/apps", tags=['bearer'])
async def apps():
    return get_apps()

I have middleware, and need to get a list of tags for the current route in the middleware.
How do I do that?
@app.middleware("http")
async def check_auth(request: Request, call_next):
    for header in request.headers:
        print("Header: %s=%s" % (header, request.headers.get(header)))
        # How do I get the tags array here so I can say - 
        if 'bearer' in ?tags?:
            check_token(request)
        ...
    return response


You certainly can't access it before you call_next; no path operation has received the request yet https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/#before-and-after-the-response.

OK, I was going to use this to mark which routes need which authentication, so I guess it's a moot point.

Looks like I'm interested in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-in-path-operation-decorators/
